# Set an attribute of a row using lxml

Tags: python, html, attributes, lxml

I want to use some logic to identify a particular row of a table in an html document and then set the background color of that row to a specific color

This code does that but it does not set the row color correctly - in that the row does not display the new color

```
for row in new_tree.xpath('//tr'):
    if row_counter == 1:
        continue
    row.set('background-color','#DDA0DD')
    row_text = row.text_content().lower()
    if 'test_word' in row_text:
        row_counter += 1
```

This is one of the results - but the row color is still white no matter what browser I use to open the file

```
<tr background-color="#DDA0DD">
```

I believe that the syntax of the html code is wrong but not sure how to correct it within lxml other than converting the row to a string and then trying to insert the style into the string - that seems too clunky

Comment: It seems like you need to set a proper inline style: `row.set("style", "background-color: #DDA0DD")`.

Comment: @mzijn Thanks post as answer and I will give you the question this was helpful and addressed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `row.set('background-color','#DDA0DD')`, you should use this:

```
row.set("style", "background-color: #DDA0DD")
```

That code will produce correct inline style markup:

```
<tr style="background-color: #DDA0DD">
```